# simple aggregation like count, max, min is extremely slow

Tags: ignite

I load my data from oracle into Ignite cache via RDMS and Ignite Integration. The cache's size is 40 million.
When I do some simple aggregation sql like the following three:

`select count(id) from Person`,

`select max(id) from Person`,

`select min(id) from Person`,

They are extremely slow, each one will take about 5 minutes.

Since they are very simple operation that could be done with map-reduced mechanism without any data movement,so it should be very fast.

Per @Valentin's Comment:

I think the `id` column has enabled the index. I am using the `ignite-schema-import.sh` to generate the CacheConfig class,and it contains the following code:

`idxs.add(new QueryIndex("id", true, "PK_ID"));`

When I run the sql to explain the plan
`explain select min(id) from Person`,

the output is

`SELECT
    MIN(ID) AS __C0
FROM "Person".PERSON
    /* "Person".PK_ID */,
SELECT
    MIN(__C0) AS __C0
FROM PUBLIC.__T0
    /* "Person"."merge_scan" */,`

Also, i am using OFFHEAP_TIERED memory mode with following code

```
cacheConfig.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
cacheConfig.setBackups(0);
cacheConfig.setMemoryMode(CacheMemoryMode.OFFHEAP_TIERED);
cacheConfig.setOffHeapMaxMemory(0);
cacheConfig.setOffHeapMaxMemory(48*1024*1024*1024);
cacheConfig.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
cacheConfig.setCopyOnRead(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `id` field is not indexed. If so, these queries imply cache scan. You can improve the performance by scaling out, but index is much better solution, especially for `min` and `max` queries.

---

**UPDATE.** It turned out that indexes are not used in this case. Here is the ticket for optimization: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4524

Comment: Thanks @Valentin. I have updated the question per your comment, please help take a look.

Comment: I checked the index information with https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-performance-and-debugging#section-using-h2-debug-console tool. Looks the index is correct.

Comment: Thanks @Valentin for helping me out on this issue, thanks!